# Display Mathematica menu for imported data

Tags: import

I am working with a medium csv file [rand.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ikXYb_hr9pPuaW4C-CmG25yHoC55mFlN/view?usp=sharing), and when I import the data into Mathematica it displays the whole content. I know that if the file is large in contents a menu like the [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtgHl.png) is diplayed, but is there a command or function to show the menu for medium sized data ?

Code: `data = Import["C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop\\rand.csv", "CSV"]`

Photo: [image: menu]

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by `is there a command or function to show the menu for medium sized data`. What is menu here? May be you just need to add `//Short` at end of your command? You might want to look at [ShortenLongOutputs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ShortenLongOutputs.html)

Comment: it looks like your data is 2D? If so, you can use `MatrixForm` also

Comment: @Nasser I used the word menu beacuse it looks for me like a menu, maybe I misused the word,

Comment: I see what you meant now. No, there is no `medium` size there, only `short` or `all` or `show more`. But why do you even need this menu? If you data is 2D, just use `MatrixForm` to display it, and use any slice size of the data you wish to see that way. `MatrixForm` is more clear any way than looking at raw data like this.

Comment: Yes, thanks, when I use `MatrixFrom` the data is shown in  a better format.

Comment: if you data is like this `data = {{{0, 0}, {0, 0.5}, {0, 1.2}}}` then make sure to do `MatrixForm[First@data]` to strip the first `{}`, alternatively you can do `MatrixForm[Flatten[data, 1]]`. Check `Dimensions[data]`. It looks like it is 2D data inside one list.